# Timezone conversation mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to convert date from one timezone to another timezone in MySQL, MySQL query which i am trying is

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ('2015-12-18 06:00:00', '+0:00', '-05:00' ),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS test
FROM appointment
```

which is working properly, now the issue is i am having timezone as America/New_York in my database.

Is there any way to convert timezone using timezone name not from timezone offset

Comment: So what happens when you use the name instead of `'-05:00'`? It looks like it should work, assuming you've got the time zone tables set up appropriately.

Comment: No i am not using any timezone table

Comment: Well you need to, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html